# HAXM error but vt-x is enabled

Tags: android, android-studio, virtualization, intel, haxm

When I am installing Intel HAXM I have the following error:

> This computer meets the requirements for HAXM, but Intel Virtualization technology (VT-x) is not turned on.
>   HAXM cannot be installed until VT-x is enabled.

So, I have checked my BiOS, VT-x is supported, and I enabled Intel virtualization (it wasn't before). I also have checked if it was really enabled with the Intel virtualization technology detection tool (Intel Processor Identification Utility) and it says:

> Intel(R) Virtualization Technology - Yes

BUT when I try again to install HAXM I have the same error as the beginning of my message. Someone has an idea?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There's also the NX, XD bit setting. 
bcdedit /set nx AlwaysOn
Make sure you use the Haxm from the web site instead of using the one downloaded through Android Studio). https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager
If you're using Avast, disable "Enable hardware-assisted virtualization" under: Settings > Troubleshooting.

Comment: Yes thanks for the answer, I solved it and I posted an answer as the time as you, but thanks :)

Comment: The bcdedit /set nx AlwaysOn was the solution for me. You have to run it in an admin cmd.

Comment: May I know what is NX, XD bit setting? bcdedit /set nx AlwaysOn? how to do it?

Comment: Tried it. Tried it all. Still no luck. But thanks for the suggestions.

Answer (score 4):

.. avast I hate you :)

Solved the problem, it was Avast.
If you have the same error check Avast.

settings tab -> troubleshooting : **uncheck** "enable hardware-assisted virtualization"

Have a nice day guys ;)

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue and it failed to install due to emulators being open (I have bluestacks loading on boot) which caused the install to report the error wrong. Make sure you have all emulators closed - fixed my problem

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, vt-x was on, hyper-v off and no antivirus as i only rely on inbuilt defender. The solution for me was to uninstall the default haxm from android studio and replaced it with the one from intel website given above by codecats.

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem and i fixed it.

1. Uninstal HAXM on control panel
2. Installing HAXM version 1.1.5
3. And I fixed the problems