# Intel HAXM is required to run this AVD

Tags: android, android-virtual-device, haxm, android-studio-3.3

I have installed Android Studio `3.3.1` and everything worked perfectly until I closed it. When I try to open a run again my project it says:

> Intel HAXM is required to run this AVD

Unknown error, What should I do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't install Intel HAXM for Android Studio. ERROR x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32011025/cant-install-intel-haxm-for-android-studio-error-x86-emulation-currently-requi)

Answer (score 14):

- Open **File Explorer**,
- Go to C:\Users\ *YourUserName* \AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\extras\intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager
- Double click on **haxm-7.6.5-setup** File and Install

This worked for me

Also check **hardware acceleration** turned on in *BIOS*

Comment: File not found. I have a dir Android\Sdk\extras\intel, but it's empty

Comment: Please check hardware acceleration turned on in BIOS

Comment: Mohammed: yeah, BIOS hardware acceleration seems to be a key part of a _complete_ answer to the question.

Answer (score 7):

In my case, I installed software which is **required to enable Hyper-V**. If you also face it, check it.
On Window (I mean I config on Window, not Ubuntu or MacOsX), it's in `"Turn Windows feature on or off"`. Uncheck Hyper-V and restart your computer.

Comment: Disable Hyper-V? Other answers say to enable it!?!?

Answer (score 6):

When Android Studio is open, click Configure on lower right corner, then select **SDK Manager** from the list. Head over to **SDK Tools**

[image: Configure button on Android Studio]

Look for Intel HAXM and make sure it's checked. If not, check the box and click apply.
And you are good to go.

[image: Intel HAXM in SDK Tools]

Make sure it is installed along with the Android Emulator. Then it should work.

Comment: How to install it manually. I want to install the latest version 7.4.1 or the previous 7.3.0?

Comment: This didn't work for me.  Even after installing with this step, Android Studio kept telling me HAXM wasn't installed.  After doing this step though, I was able to find "haxm-7.6.5-setup.exe" in "~\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\extras\intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager" and running that setup file fixed the issue.

Comment: Fails with "Intel® HAXM installation failed. To install Intel® HAXM follow the instructions found at: https://github.com/intel/haxm/wiki/Installation-Instructions-on-Windows"

Answer (score 5):

Enabling

> Hyper-V

or

> Windows Hypervisor Platform

fixed the problem for me

Comment: Really? Other answers say to disable hyper-v!?!?

Comment: @steve : were you able to solve it? I cannot find any of the solution working here and dont have hyper-v in windows feature. I am running on i3 first gen

Comment: @yesarpit: I got it working yes. I think I did enable the hyper-v feature, but I'm I don't quite remember (there's often a fog about what I try and didn't try) and even if I did I don't know whether that helped at all. Eventually, I read the last dialog of the HAXM installer that said I needed to enable virtualization in the BIOS. After doing that (which was a hassle!) it started working. ... I think this may be one of those issues where there's no one answer. I think there are several things one must do to get the emulator/simulator/avd working. Good luck!!

Comment: This worked although other answers told to disable Hyper-V but mine was already disabled. So turning that windows feature on fixed it.

Answer (score 3):

Try install it manually. You will find the .exe setup here ~\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\extras\intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager

Answer (score 1):

I tried many times with android studio many times but the worked well is

This didn't work for me. Even after installing with this step, Android Studio kept telling me HAXM wasn't installed. After doing this step though, I was able to find "haxm-7.6.5-setup.exe" in "~\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\extras\intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager" and running that setup file fixed the issue.

Comment: Huh? Makes no sense. "the worked well is"? What didn't work for you? Installing with what step? What step?

Answer (score 1):

[image]

my case, just add this configuration

Answer (score 0):

Enable Windows feature `Hyper-V` in Program and Features You problem will get solved

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty old question, but I got the error when trying to run an android emulator/simulator/avd (whatever it's called) after installing android studio 2022.1 on a clean windows 11 laptop.

First, why the heck does Android Studio require an optimization in order for the emulator to work? I would expect it to work regardless; maybe slower without the optimization. But that's neither here nor there. It is required and it's a PITA.

Other answers say you need to enable windows feature Hyper-V (or Windows Hypervisor Platform) and others say you need to disable it!! I don't think it matters. I tried it with and without and seems to have no effect -- either to fix the problem or to cause the problem once I did get it fixed.

But, maybe it does need to be enabled (or disabled) in some situations like older Android Studio or Windows 10 or other computers. So many, configurations.

Anyway, what I had to do was read the message at the end of HAXM installed :). Normally, the last message of an installer is super boring so I never read it. But, this one said I needed to enable virtualization in the BIOS. Doing that was a PITA, but it did fix the problem.

FWIW I installed HAXM 7.8.0 directly, not via Android Studio. But, it might work via AS too.

Answer (score 0):

`Go to turn windows feat on or off -> check enable in Hyper-V` 
This solution work with me 
(**remember that you have to install HAXM first**)