# Android Virtual Device still complaining of HAXM after installing AMD emulator

Tags: android, android-studio

Am using an

> AMD A6-5200 APU with Radeon 
>   and I installed
>
> Android Studio 
>   and all its components like the emulator but when I created the
>
> Android Virtual Device

, it keeps complaining that I install the

> HAXM

despite using

> AMD processor

.

These are the steps taken so far
Step 1: After installing the android studio

Step 2: I install the android emulator

Step 3: I install the Android Emulator Hypervisor Driver for AMD processors.

Step 4: I created and configure the AVD and clicked the finish button.

Step 5: I activated the Hyper-V

Step 6: In the BIOS settings, I enabled the VT

Step 7: I clicked on the "Play" button which is present under the action column to start Android Emulator.

Then it gave this error at step 7,

> intel HAXM is required to run AVD. HAXM is not installed

How can I solve this problem

Comment: have you enable Virtual Technology from bios?

Comment: I had your same issue and i solved with this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54955446/intel-haxm-is-required-to-run-this-avd

Comment: @LudoviKush that is for Intel processors. He says he has AMD processor.

Comment: Have you ever solved this problem? Does installing HAXM do anything?

Comment: @EvrenYurtesen No. What I finally do was use expo.io. It comes with an online android emulator