# Whenever i try to launch this AVD it says the following though i have installed it.what should i do?

Tags: react-native, android-studio

[I have already installed HAXM installer but everytime i try to launch this avd it says "HAXM not installed" and gives an error of "Couldnot launch AVD"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RZJdJ.png)

Comment: Found this on another post, could try it:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54955446/intel-haxm-is-required-to-run-this-avd

This didn't work for me. Even after installing with this step, Android Studio kept telling me HAXM wasn't installed. After doing this step though, I was able to find "haxm-7.6.5-setup.exe" in "~\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\extras\intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager" and running that setup file fixed the issue.

Comment: where should i type this "~\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\extras\intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager" i have no idea.I'm totally a beginner on android studio.Could you please help me?

Comment: The above is a path in your file explorer, so it's a folder that should exist on your machine.