# How to update intel HAXM in android studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-emulator, boot

I am trying to update intel HAXM x86 in my android studio because my emulator is running slow and stuck on booting screen (Google logo screen) and I think the version of HAXM is causing the problem, I have tried updating from SDK Manager but it is showing me version 7.6.5 but I searched on internet the latest version is 7.8.0 but I am unable to update it to latest version but I have already installed the latest version directly on windows outside of android studio, so if anyone know how to update and why my emulator is stuck on booting screen, Please help

Please help me solve this issue I am literally getting frustrated because of my emulator is stuck on booting screen and I am unable to code because of that.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: it will help to you:   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32011025/cant-install-intel-haxm-for-android-studio-error-x86-emulation-currently-requi

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue like you and I try to do the steps below and it helped me.

1. Go to Turn Windows features on or off. Default, my laptop untick on Hyper-V.
2. Tick on Hyper-V, click Ok. Then restart computer.
3. Go to android studio and run app. It's ok for me!

I hope this will help you.
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ipfXx.png)