# Using Android Studio Emulator on Windows 10 Home

Tags: android, android-studio, hyper-v, haxm

I'm kinda a beginner to Android Studio and I couldn't find a solution for this problem. I've always used Android Studio on my MacBook, but now I needed to use it in my PC. The problem is, when I try to run the emulator, it tells that I need to enable VT-x. I enabled it from my BIOS settings, but I also needed to enable it from control panel in system functions. The problem is that, reading around, I've found that Hyper-v function can be enabled only in Windows 10 Pro version, while I own a Home version. Now, I can't use Android Studio Emulator in my PC only cause I don't own Windows 10 Pro? That sounds kinda weird to me...

Some help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Did you install Intel HAXM from the SDK Manager?

Comment: @simon yeah I did, that's not the problem.

Comment: Try to reinstall HAXM. Hyper-V is not needed (it must even be disabled on Win 10 Pro), enabling VT-x and installing HAXM should be enough.

Comment: @simon already tryied, still not working...

Comment: Do you get any error?

Comment: @simon It tells I have to enable VT-x. I have already enabled it, but seems like you have to enable also Hyper-V.

Comment: I doubt that this is related to Hyper-V because I use Win10 Home myself and I don't have any problems. Did you check other questions on this topic? E.g. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28748754/haxm-error-but-vt-x-is-enabled) mentions issues caused by antivirus software

Comment: @simon are you sure you are using the android studio emulator with win10 home?

Comment: Yes I am. I also don't have a Hyper-V option so I guess the problem lies somewhere else.

Comment: @Simone I too have same issue, have you found the solution ? Please share if yes.

Comment: See also https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/b03v5c/android_studio_on_amd_windows_10_home/, https://www.itechtics.com/enable-hyper-v-windows-10-home/, https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/202188690?pli=1, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68373280/android-studio-emulator-is-not-working-on-windows-11-using-whpx

Comment: And https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61047505/how-to-use-android-emulator-on-amd-ryzen-android-studio.

Answer (score 6):

Android Studio Emulator runs on Windows 10 Home. In my case,  HAXM  was installed but only partially because virtualization was not enabled.

For HAXM to install correctly, Virtualization must be enabled on the Intel CPU and this can be done through the UEFI bios settings. It is normally disabled by default, so if this has not been specifically enabled it will probably still be disabled and HAXM installation will not finish installing.

You can download a cpu utility such as Speccy to see if the Virtualization  status is enabled or disabled and then re-install HAXM after Virtualization is enabled. Android Studio Emulator should  then run on Windows 10 Home without problems.

Comment: What about docker desktop for windows home that uses wls? When docker is activated, they conflict.